# Database Migration Library which supports multiple database types

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, fluent-migrator

I am trying to enable support for multiple database types in our application developed in ASP.NET Core.

For the ORM layer, we are using EF Core.

Hence using EF Core Migrations seems to be a natural progression but by default, EF Core seems to generate database-specific migration code for each database.

This seems to be a little weird since EF Core can easily generate SELECT queries for multiple database types, on the fly by just changing the Database Adapter.

Trying to maintain multiple migration sets for each database type seems to be a little tedious. Is this the standard approach for people who support multiple database types?

Currently, I am using FluentMigrator which seems to handle switching between databases better and allows me to maintain a single Migrations project. Although it is a little unintuitive to sync between the Create commands of FluentMigrator and the Entity classes used by EF Core.

Is there a better way to approach this issue?

Comment: The usual approach is to have separate migration assemblies for each db provider.

Comment: I've also done some tests with this and ended up creating dedicated projects with migrations for each DB. If you're interested to have a look, the four DataAccess.EF projects might be interesting https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend

Comment: Thanks, @Philippe and abdusco. So, basically supporting a database provider is a full-time job. I was hoping things would be a little simpler than this. Will look into adding separate Migration projects for each database provider. I am facing a lot of issues trying to sync FluentMigrator with the Entity objects.